# System reboot and shut-down from flask app inside docker

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, raspberry-pi

I have an application that is now working on Ubuntu, but eventually it should work on Raspberry Pi. Whole app is turn on with docker-compose up. There are three containers inside it, one of it is Flask Api written in Python. Now I need to add two endpoints for my Flask Api. One for system shutdown and one for system reebot.

I wanted to write some python code or bash script that would perform this actions, but the problem here is that everyting is working on docker. So for example simple linux command `shutdown -h now` is not working, because docker is telling that shutdown is not found. Is it possible to shutdown ubuntu/ raspberry pi from app running in docker?

Comment: No, that's a security risk.  A container should never be able to shut down the server.  If it's a dedicated Rpi, who not just run the web site globally, without Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Debian based systems (assuming you are running raspbian on your raspberry pi) `shutdown` and `reboot` are just symlinks to `systemctl`.

So you need to be able to run `systemctl` commands on the host from within docker. This can be achieved with a few volume mounts. Here is an example snippet for the `docker-compose` file:

```
  ShutdownContainer:
  image: ShutdownImage:latest
  links:
    - "rebootContainer:latest"
  volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup
      - /bin/systemctl:/bin/systemctl 
      - /run/systemd/system:/run/systemd/system 
      - /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup
  command:
    - "startYourWebserver"
```

With these volumes mapped you should be able to run `systemctl shutdown` or `systemctl reboot` from within the docker container. It might be necessary to run the containers in privilege mode.